# Getting YouTube Views using re.search()

Tags: python

Trying to scrape hundreds of YouTube videos to get view counts. This code used to work well for me, however recently  it's been acting up as it appears that YouTube may have altered how the view total appears for videos that have hundreds of thousands, or millions, of views. Looking to get the most precise number of views possible. This is what I have:

```
def getViews(link):
try:
    page = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+link)
    print("success get")
    views = re.search("[>](\d*.?\d*.?\d*.?\d*) views", page.text)
    print(views)
    views = int(views.replace(",","")) # OTHERWISE IT'S A STRING
    print("Success - %s views" % views)
    return views
except:
    print("Failed")
```

Not sure how to get my re.search() back in to a working state at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Python fans for **scraping** here. I don't think you can search the views from Youtube using `requests` unless you want to check the API one by one.

I recommend [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python).

This is the example of the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = Options()
// headless so browser can be instanced without showing the GUI
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DhWFIrQeDA")
// wait until the page is loaded, assume it 5 seconds to load
views = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    lambda driver: driver.find_elements(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="count"]/yt-view-count-renderer/span[1]'
    ))
views = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="count"]/yt-view-count-renderer/span[1]').text
print(views)

OUTPUT:
» python main.py
175,520 views
```

I have tested, and yes, YouTube change their mechanism using AJAX to show the views and `requests` can't get that without get the JS file that responsible to show it. Here is the snapshot what YouTube show or `requests.get`:

[image: Using links]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Suggestion to use the YouTube API is more helpful in my case, as I'm parsing through 1,000s of YouTube videos to pull view counts. Selenium I don't think would be able to do this task quickly? Otherwise, I was able to get the job done using the requests_html library.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using `import requests_html`

```
# START UP A REQUESTS_HTML SESSION FOR OUR FUNCTION BELOW
session = requests_html.HTMLSession()

# DEFINE A FUNCTION THAT WILL RETRIEVE YOUTUBE VIEWS BY HYPERLINK
def getViews(link):
    try:
        page = session.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+link)
        views = page.html.search('viewCount":"{}"')[0]
        views = int(views.replace(",","")) # OTHERWISE IT'S A STRING
        print("Success - %s views" % views)
        return views
    except:
        print("Failed")
```